# JavaScript object output in console.log

Tags: javascript, class, new-operator, console.log

I want to know from where does console.log get the name of the constructing function when printing an object. Also, does that actually effect anything code wise?

```
function F() { 
    this.test = 'ok';
}

var f = new F();

console.log( f );
```

The output of console.log (in Chrome) is:
    F {test: "ok"}

Where does the console.log get the `F` in `F {test...`?

If I change `F.constructor`, `F.prototype`, and `f.constructor` to something random, it still prints the original `F`:

```
function G() {
    this.fail = 'bad';
}

function F() { 
    this.test = 'ok';
}

F.prototype = G;
F.constructor = G;

var f = new F();

console.log( f );
```

The output is still the same - `F {test: "ok"}`

Is this information is simply kept privately by the browser, my question is does it affect JavaScript code in any way? That is, will it creep up during comparison or inheritance, after I override the constructor's `prototype` and `constructor` properties?

**UPDATE**

The original purpose was to do the following.

```
function Person ( _name ) {
    this.name = _name;
}

function Construct( _constructor, _args, _context ) {
    function F () {
        var context = _context || this;
        return _constructor.apply( context, _args );
    }

    /* I want to have the constructed object by identified 
       as _constructor and not a F */
    F.prototype = _constructor.prototype;

    return new F();
}

function Make ( _who ) {
    if ( 'person' === _who ) {
        /* Remove the first argument, who, and pass along all the rest.
           Constructors cannot be called with .apply so I have to use 
           this technique. */
        return Construct( Person, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ) );
    }
}

var dev = Make( 'person', 'John Doe' );

console.log( dev ); // prints `F {name: "John Doe"}`
```

As you can see, the resulting print of `dev` outputs `F {name: "John Doe"}`, which made me question whether I may run into problems later on if I'd like to make comparisons or inheritance with instances constructed in such a way.

Comment: I have added another answer which targets the original problem you had, instead of just trying to get your solution to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing `F.prototype` replaces the content of `F`, not the name. The old prototype object still exists and a reference to it is stored internally in each instance of the old `F`. You cam check it by calling [`f.__proto__`´](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto) (deprecated) or [`Object.getPrototypeOf(f)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf).

Note that `__proto__` is an accessor proterty (internally a getter, not a real property), so it cannot be changed.

Comment: Note the links to `Object.setPrototypeOf` in both the specifications of `__proto__` and `Object.getPrototypeOf`. That function, while supported by Mozilla, is considered experimental - and its use is discouraged as well. Reasons given in the spec.

Comment: Although OP has changed prototype object `F.prototype = G;` ignore it for a while. Lets change `F.prototype.constructor = G;` instead. Now `Object.getPrototypeOf(f).constructor` or `f.__proto__.constructor` is also `G`. But `console.log(f)` still prints `F`. So, I don't know how this post answers the question.

Comment: @YK1 This may be browser-dependant. Using current version of Firefox, changing `__proto__` changes the output for me.

Comment: For me, its more important that programmatically `f` is recognized as G. If that's the case but console.log prints it out as F and that's the only caveat, I will be happy.

Comment: the `instanceof` operator fopr example compares the `.prototype` objects afaik. SO if you replace them (using `someF.prototype` instead of `F.prototype`) it should work. Not sure about this however. YOu may read the documentation of everything you want to do with the prototype very carefully.

Comment: @JohannesH.: I see, yes, after changing `F.prototype.constructor = G;` firebug prints `G` but chrome dev tools still print `F`.

Comment: SO, my answer isn't global then, but only helpful for firebug / firefox. Didn't know they were different - one keeps learning every day ;)

Answer (score 1):

It's not difficult, because f is finally an instance of F and the order of scope resolving (this, prototype, ...) is obvious :-)

For example, you can run this code and you'll see that in this case it will print G:

```
function G() {
    this.fail = 'bad';
}

function F() { 
    this.test = 'ok';
}

F.prototype = G;
F.constructor = G;

var f = new F();  // Prints F

console.log(f);

f.prototype = G;  // Redefining f type info
f.constructor = G;

console.log(f);  // Prints G
```

Comment: you answer leads than to the conclusion that `F.prototype = G;
F.constructor = G;` were unnecessary...

Comment: @JohannesH. yes cause you're creating a new instance of: `var f = new F();` see the `F` ?

Comment: QUestion was: how does the browser know that, if all references to F has been changed. (of course the answer is "they haven't", but the point is: where is that last instance?).

the vbrowser doesn'T parse the sourcecode to look for the initial creation of the object,  the type can indeed be determined at runtime.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Difference between this code and the OPs code is: devlato is changing `f.prototype` as well (which indeed changes the type the object has), OP didn't.

Comment: @JohannesH it's common place that if you assign to a `var f` an object - console will try to show the reference function name (+object). Otherwise what OP expects doing i.e: `console.log( f.fail );` ? Nothing cause will return `undefined`

Comment: All true. Still there has to be a way for the browser to get that info, which is what the OP wanted to know.

Answer (score 0):

Your creating a new instance of F, so the browser prints that in order to help you keep track of your logging. Even though you change the prototype would you still have to create a new "F" in order to get the object.

```
function A () { something: 123 }
new A();
console.log result: A {}
new B();
console.log result: ReferenceError: B is not defined
```

Comment: That dopesn't quite answer the question... the point is: why does the browser know which type the object has, even if it'S constuctor has been replaced and the prototype has been changed?

Comment: Ahh, misunderstood the question then. Won't make an edit though as you've already got an answer which I feel explains it well.

Answer (score 0):

`object.constructor.name` is another way of getting the name of an object constructor.

Comment: not if you changed `object.constructor` (which is ok to do and works fine), just as the OP did :)

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest another approach for the original intention? There is no problem with just using a different reference to the prototype object instead of the original one, so you can do

```
function construct(constructor, args, context) { //lowercase, as it's a function, not a class
    return new constructor(args);
}
```

This should create the right object in the first place, no need to swap any prototypes.

Comment: The problem there is that now constructor will now receive an array [ 'John Doe' ] instead of a string 'John Doe'. I know I can account for that using typeof checks but I want Person's constructor to use the same signature.