# Where does "TextRow" come from when logging mysql results in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

Using mysql with node, when I console.log the results of a query it comes like this:

`TextRow {id: 6, user_id: 'asdg'}`

Where does the JavaScript interpreter learn "TextRow"? When I do JSON.stringify on the object I get

`'{"id":6,"user_id":"asdg"}'`

So it appears to not be part of the object but maybe an inferred type?
This behavior occurs in the locals section while debugging as well.

I'm using VSCode.

Answer (score 1):

code: https://github.com/sidorares/node-mysql2/blob/master/lib/packets/text_row.js

```
class TextRow { 
    // ...
    static fromPacket(packet) {
    // packet.reset(); // set offset to starting point?
    const columns = [];
    while (packet.haveMoreData()) {
      columns.push(packet.readLengthCodedString());
    }
    return new TextRow(columns);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. It looks like my question is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21590205/javascript-object-output-in-console-log The TextRow name is grabbed from the class name. If you add more explanation to yours I'll mark it as the answer.